# Converting xx:xx:xx time formation to minutues in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a dataset that has a duration field in time format, I'm trying to convert this into just minutues however haven't been succesful in doing so.

Is there a formula to convert these formats into mintues or seconds.

The format is HH:MM:SS some examples of data displayed and required output below.

Example

00:01:00 = 1

00:01:30 = 1.5

00:02:00 = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether Excel sees these as DateTime or Text.  To know this you can put `=ISNUMBER( cell address )`.  If true, then it is DateTime.  You can do `=ISTEXT( cell address )` to see if it is text.

If it is DateTime, you can use this to convert it to minutes:

```
= A1 * 24 * 60
```

to convert it to minutes (where A1 is the cell with the 00:xx:xx value).

If text, then you need to do:

```
=TIMEVALUE(A1)*24*60
```

And even if it is already datetime, you can use `=TIMEVALUE( cell address )*24*60` - it will figure out if it is text or already datetime.